# Поиск минимального элемента массива через указатель

Tags: c++

Доброго времени суток! 
Нужно реализовать очередь на базе массива. Допустим, массив из 5 элементов. Затем нужно найти максимальный элемент, используя указатели. Но у меня максимальным почему-то всегда оказывается первый. Где ошибка?

```
int mas[5];
int* ptrmas = mas;
int* head = ptrmas;
int* tail = ptrmas + 4;

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    cin >> mas[i];
}

int* max = ptrmas;

while (*head != *tail)
{
    head++;

    if (*head > *max)
        max = head;
}

if (*tail > *max)
    max = tail;

cout << "Максимальный элемент последовательности =" << *max << "\n";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш код нормально работает. Может, вы всегда вводите первым максимальный элемент? :)

Другое дело, что вот это

```
if (*tail > *max)
    max = tail;
```

у вас явно лишнее...

Comment: Спасибо, я поняла ошибку. Перед поиском минимального элемента, я находила сумму элементов, и ,похоже, не учла, что указатели сдвинулись